# How to edit the (metadata) "comments" field of a folder?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, metadata

Any idea how to edit that "comments" field?

Is there a tweak available that would allow to simply click on the comment field to edit it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### Any idea how to edit that "comments" field?

Use the following VBS script.

> My system is windows 10 64 bit.
>
> I've solved it with a vbs script.
>
> - First I change the folder attributes to "system folder".
> - Then I placed an Desktop.INI file inside the folder with the comments as a parameter "InfoTip". You can change the comments inside
>     the INI file later to change the comments field.
>
> This is the script (you can drag a folder on the script to use it):
>
> ```
> 'CreateFolderComments.vbs
> 'On Error Resume Next
>
> Dim Foldername
> Dim strMessage
> Dim oShell
> Dim fs
>
> Set fs = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
> strMessage = Inputbox("Comments","Input Comments")
> Foldername = Wscript.Arguments(0)
> 'Msgbox chr(34) & Foldername & chr(34)
> Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")
> oShell.run "C:\Windows\System32\attrib +s " & chr(34) & FolderName & chr(34)
> Set Tekstfile = fs.CreateTextFile(FolderName & "\Desktop.Ini", True)
>
> Tekstfile.writeline("[.ShellClassInfo]")
> Tekstfile.writeline("InfoTip=" & strMessage)
>
> MsgBox "DONE !"
> ```

Source [In Window Explorer, How do we add a Comment for a folder? - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-desktop/in-window-explorer-how-do-we-add-a-comment-for-a/cf165d11-8bd0-4a95-947b-24d3d9969804?db=5)

---

#### Is there a tweak available that would allow to simply click on the comment field to edit it?

No, but see above script.

Comment: thanks! But what do you mean by `First I change the folder attributes to "system folder".`? (What must I do, concretely?)

Comment: @JinSnow I'm guessing something like `attrib +s <path>`