# Bulk edit SFX script

Tags: windows, winrar, file-attributes, comments

I create custom portable versions of apps using WinRAR's SFX module (among other things, the setup option `Run after extraction`). In the cases where 32-bit / x86 and 64-bit / x64 versions are available, I use `init.bat` to dynamically choose which to run depending on the execution environment.

[image]

For Cyber Essentials Plus compliance reasons, Group Policy was configured to associate the file extension `.bat` with Notepad so that they cannot be directly executed. This is good for security but broke my portable apps so I need to mass edit the EXE files' comments / SFX scripts replacing `init.bat` with `cmd.exe /k init.bat`.

After much Googling, all I have found is:

1. [Windows file "comment" attribute](https://superuser.com/questions/1357659/windows-file-comment-attribute) with no answer.
2. PowerShell commandlets like `Get-ItemProperty` don't seem to get comments.
3. https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/66937-adding-comments-files-files-explorer-windows-10-a.html#post842655 but File Meta didn't seem to work - the exported XML file always only contained `<Metadata/>`.
4. [How to edit the (metadata) "comments" field of a folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/1293190/how-to-edit-the-metadata-comments-field-of-a-folder) but that's for folders, not files.
5. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/trying-to-add-comments-to-files-in-windows/8a4e2c4b-8712-47bb-8648-0a6dcddab864?page=3 with no real answers.

it seems that it isn't really possible to edit file comments in modern versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that WinRAR itself is capable of editing the archive comment:
[image]

So, I read https://ss64.com/bash/rar.html and http://acritum.com/winrar/console-rar-manual then created the following PowerShell script which did what I wanted:

```
$RARFile_Path = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe";
$EXEFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "<folder path>" -Filter *.exe -Recurse -File;
$SFXSetup_Original = "Setup=init.bat";
$SFXSetup_New = "Setup=cmd.exe /k init.bat";

ForEach ($EXEFile in $EXEFiles){
    $EXEFile_Path = $EXEFile.FullName;
    $EXEFile_Name = $EXEFile.Name;

    $EXEFile_Comment = & $RARFile_Path cw $EXEFile_Path -inul;

    If ($EXEFile_Comment -And $EXEFile_Comment -Like $SFXSetup_Original){
        <#
        Write-Output "Comment, before:";
        Write-Output $EXEFile_Comment;
        Write-Output "";
        #>

        $CommentFile_Original_Path = $Env:TMP + "\" + $EXEFile_Name + " comment (original).txt";
        If (Test-Path -Path $CommentFile_Original_Path){
            Remove-Item -Path $CommentFile_Original_Path -Force;
        }

        & $RARFile_Path cw $EXEFile_Path $CommentFile_Original_Path -inul;
        $CommentFile_Original_Content = Get-Content -Path $CommentFile_Original_Path -Raw;

        $CommentFile_New_Path = $Env:TMP + "\" + $EXEFile_Name + " comment (new).txt";
        $CommentFile_New_Content = $CommentFile_Original_Content -Replace $SFXSetup_Original, $SFXSetup_New;
        Set-Content -Path $CommentFile_New_Path -Value $CommentFile_New_Content;

        <#
        Write-Output "Comment, after:";
        Write-Output $CommentFile_New_Content;
        #>

        & $RARFile_Path c "-z$CommentFile_New_Path" $EXEFile_Path -inul;

        <#
        Write-Output "";
        Write-Output "";
        Write-Output "";
        #>
    }
}
```